# custom std::set comparator using function pointer

Tags: c++

Is it possible that I can declare a set with function pointer as its comparator as a data member?

```
bool lex_compare (const int& lhs, const int & rhs){
       return true;
    };

// So I can define a std::set testSet using function pointer:
set<int, bool(*)(const int & lhs, const int & rhs)> testSet (&lex_compare);
```

My question is How should I declare and define testSet as a data member using a function pointer as comparator?

NOTE: I know that functor can be a solution in my situation:

```
struct lex_compare {
    bool operator() (const int& lhs, const int& rhs) const{
        return ture;
    }
};

set<int, lex_compare> testSet;
```

I ma interested if there is a way that function pointer can do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is How should I declare and define testSet as a data member using a function pointer as comparator?

You can declare it just like you have,

```
set<int, bool(*)(const int &, const int &)> testSet;
```

You can initialize it in the member initialization list of a constructor.

```
MyClass::MyClass() : testSet (&lex_compare) { ... }
```

**Recommended**

You can simplify `lex_compare` to:

```
bool lex_compare (int lhs, int rhs){ ... }
```

Comment: I got bitten by not using the correct type i.e. `decltype(lex_compare)` instead of the correct `decltype(&lex_compare)` as Vaughn helpfully pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

It's basically the same if you are doing this inside a class:

```
struct MyClass {
    static bool lex_compare (const int& lhs, const int & rhs){
           return ...;
        };

    set<int, bool(*)(const int & lhs, const int & rhs)> testSet;

    MyClass()
    : testSet(&lex_compare)
    {
    }
};
```

Making your `lex_compare` function be static makes it be a regular function so that you can get a regular function pointer to it.

With C++11 or later, this can be simplified:

```
struct MyClass {
    static bool lex_compare(const int& lhs, const int & rhs){
           return ...;
        };

    set<int, decltype(&lex_compare)> testSet {lex_compare};
};
```

As noted by R Sahu, using plain ints as parameters is better, so this becomes:

```
struct MyClass {
    static bool lex_compare(int lhs, int rhs) { return ...; }
    set<int, decltype(&lex_compare)> testSet {lex_compare};
};
```